# How to set the shell of remote server through perl telnet

Tags: perl, bash, telnet, env

How can I set the remote server shell to bash through the perl telnet?

My code is below:

```
$telnet = Net::Telnet->new(Timeout=>90,Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open($ipAddress);
$telnet->login($username,$password);
$telnet->waitfor('/$/');
$telnet->print("exec bash");
print "after bash";
print $telnet->cmd("ls -lrt");
print $telnet->cmd("cd $homePath");
```

In the above code, after the exec bash statement, none of the commands are getting executed.  I need to set the remote shell as bash because some of the processes I need to run after this lines require env settings.

Please let me know how can I do the same.

Comment: maybe try `/bin/bash`? or `exec $SHELL`?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex to wait for the command prompt is wrong

```
$telnet->waitfor('/$/');
```

Try

```
$telnet->waitfor('/\$ $/');
```

Even better, see the first example in the Net::Telnet 3.04 doc:

```
my $host = 'your_destination_host_here';
my $user = 'your_username_here';
my $passwd = 'your_password_here';
my ($t, @output);

## Create a Net::Telnet object.
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout  => 10);

## Connect and login.
$t->open($host);

$t->waitfor('/login: ?$/i');
$t->print($user);

$t->waitfor('/password: ?$/i');
$t->print($passwd);

## Switch to a known shell, using a known prompt.
$t->prompt('/<xPROMPTx> $/');
$t->errmode("return");

$t->cmd("exec /usr/bin/env 'PS1=<xPROMPTx> ' /bin/sh -i")
    or die "login failed to remote host $host";

$t->errmode("die");

## Now you can do cmd() to your heart's content.
@output = $t->cmd("uname -a");
print @output;
```